# Is an Activity equal to a Context?

Tags: java, android

I've been wondering about something in android development.

I have a class for requesting permissions to the device in an easier way for me, this class name is `PermissionRequester`

```
public class PermissionRequester{
    int sdk;
    Context context;

    public PermissionRequester(Context context) {
                this.context = context;
                sdk = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            }
}
```

In a beginning, I was requesting a Context in my constructor for checking if the permission was allowed or denied by the user. Using Context didn't work, so I change "Context" to "Activity" and it worked.

```
public class PermissionRequester {
    int sdk;
    Activity activity;

    public PermissionRequester(Activity activity) {
                this.activity = activity;
                sdk = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            }
}
```

In my MainActivity, I instanciate like this

```
PermissionRequester requester = new PermissionRequester(MainActivity.this);
```

So my question is the next:

> - Why didn't I get a compile error in both cases using Context and Activity?

Comment: "This didn't work" -- what does this mean, specifically? "Why didn't I get a compile error in both cases using Context and Activity?" -- what was the compile error, and on what code did you get that error?

Comment: @CommonsWare I didn't get any compile error, that's why I want to know why. Using context is what didn't work.

Comment: "Using Context didn't work" -- what kind of error did you get or what exactly didn't work?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your bullet. However, you have not explained what "This didn't work" means. I understand that `Context` caused some problem, but you have not explained what the problem is, other than it was not a compile error. Based on the code in your question, you are not using either the `Context` or the `Activity`, as your classes are empty except for constructors. My guess is that your problem lies in the code that you did not show, and we cannot help you with that code. You may need to expand your [mcve] to show exactly what you tried and explain exactly what the results were.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Context` is the Base Object. To be more precise an `Activity` is a specialization of `Context`. That's why you `Activity` works in your case.

Take a look at this architecture of an `Activity`:

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.content.Context
       ↳    android.content.ContextWrapper
           ↳    android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
               ↳    android.app.Activity
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to DEX7RA's answer.

Another important Context is Appication, which is base class for those who need to maintain global application state. You can provide your own implementation by specifying its name in your AndroidManifest.xml's  tag, which will cause that class to be instantiated for you when the process for your application/package is created.

I usually do application wide initialization in Application's OnCreate event, like creating database, log file, etc.